# Check if a sheet is open

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, appkit, cocoa-sheet

I'm writing a Cocoa app and basically I have a window and I need to check if a sheet is open before I open another window. Google doesn't seem to know that one. How may I check if the sheet is open or not?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`-[NSWindow attachedSheet]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
BOOL hasSheet = ([window attachedSheet] != nil);
```